# About second derivative test: $\Delta>0$ and $f_{xx}=0$

Tags: calculus

I was reading the second derivative test of real function with two variables. I found that they missed a case, namely the determinant of hessian being positive and $f_{xx}=0$. Why is that? Or maybe this case cannot happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\det H= f_{xx} f_{yy} - f_{xy} f_{yx}=0-(f_{xy})^2$$
So if $f_{xx}=0$ (and $f$ is real), then $\det H\le0$